# convert a N*M DF to 1D DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose that we have the following DF:

```
        Temp_max    Temp_min    Vent        
mean    16.800000   26.366667   26.466667   
std     5.202122    5.486556    8.488261    
min     4.000000    11.000000   11.000000
```

I want to have to Convert this DF from 3*3 cell to 1*9 cell like this:

```
Temp_max_mean Temp_max_std Temp_max_min Temp_min_mean Temp_min_std Temp_min_min Vent_mean Vent_std Vent_min
16.800000     5.202122     4.000000     26.366667     5.486556     11.000000    26.466667 8.488261 11.000000
```

Is there any predifined function to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```py
df = df.unstack().to_frame().T
df.columns = ['_'.join(column) for column in df.columns]
```